# Javascript function when called in another function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a simple website (locally, I plan to use this as a personal tool) where I can input text in an organized way and edit where I see fit. To organize the categories, I wanted to include a feature where I could add a whole new text field (Here I use dividers for the sake of auto resize based on content) by the click of a button. This proved a bit more challenging than I thought.

P.S. I am not professional **at all**. I am a complete amateur and have probably done half the stuff wrong.

Help would really be appreciated! Code listed below:

```js
function EDITTHIS() {
  document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').contentEditable = 'true';
  document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').style = 'background:yellow';
}

function ENDTHIS() {
  document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').contentEditable = 'false';
  document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').style = 'background:palegreen';
}

function AMPLIFYER() {

  function CREATION(element, element_id, element_text) {

    var element_a = document.createElement(element);
    element_a.setAttribute("id", element_id);
    var element_text = document.createTextNode(elemet_name);
    element_a.appendChild(element_text);
    document.body.appendChild(element_a);

  }


  CREATION("DIV", "DIVTHAT", "Write Here.");
  CREATION("BUTTON", "EDITTHAT", "EDIT");
  CREATION("BUTTON", "DONETHAT", "DONE");
}

function CREATION(element, element_id, element_text) {

  var element_a = document.createElement(element);
  element_a.setAttribute("id", element_id);
  var element_text = document.createTextNode(elemet_name);
  element_a.appendChild(element_text);
  document.body.appendChild(element_a);

}
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 105px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: none;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
}

button {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: solid green;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

div {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 1140px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("BG.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Welcome to FELRYN</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h1>FELRYN</h1>
  </center>
  <h2>Description of World:</h2>
  <div id="DESCRIPTION" contentEditable="false" style="background:palegreen">Write the description here.</div>
  <br />
  <button id="WANNAEDIT?" onclick="EDITTHIS()"> Edit</button>
  <button id="DONEEDIT?" onclick="ENDTHIS()"> Done</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button id="MULTIPLY!" onclick="AMPLIFYER()">Create New Feild.</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You do realize you've declared the function `CREATION` twice, don't you? Is there a reason you've done that?

Comment: What function is it exactly that is not working for you?

Comment: FYI, nice job indenting your code.  Much easier to read.  As a matter of code style, typically functions in javascript are spelled as `editThis` as opposed to all uppercase: `EDITHIS`.  All uppercase is often used to denote a "constant" ( a value / variable that cannot / should not ever change value)

Comment: My answer is updated and fully functionional now sorry got sidetracked with some other projects

Comment: Yes I realized I made the function twice after I posted it lol. And I know about the names being in a helloWorld format but for readability almost all id names and whatnot are all caps so I can see them. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Oh and for the function that simply doesn't seem to be working that would be the AMPLIFYER function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `element_name` to `element_text` and it will add the new fields. Or pass that variable to `creation` if you want to use name. 
You will need to add a counter to keep track the new editable divs unique ids as well. This is a fully functioning answer.

```js
var count = 1;

function AMPLIFYER() {
  CREATION("DIV", "DIVTHAT", "Write Here.");
  CREATION("BUTTON", "EDITTHAT", "EDIT");
  CREATION("BUTTON", "DONETHAT", "DONE");
  count++
  moveAddBtn()
}

function CREATION(element, element_id, element_text) {
  var element_a = document.createElement(element);
  element_a.setAttribute("id", element_id + count);
  if (element_text == "EDIT") {
    element_a.setAttribute('onclick', "EDITTHIS(" + count + ")")
  }
  if (element_text == "DONE") {
    element_a.setAttribute('onclick', "ENDTHIS(" + count + ")")
  }
  var element_text = document.createTextNode(element_text);
  element_a.appendChild(element_text);
  document.body.appendChild(element_a);  
}

function moveAddBtn() {
  var element = document.getElementById("MULTIPLY!");
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element)
  var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
  document.body.appendChild(linebreak);
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function EDITTHIS(x) {
  let editDiv = document.getElementById('DIVTHAT' + x)
  editDiv.contentEditable = 'true';
  editDiv.style = 'background:yellow';
}

function ENDTHIS(x) {
  let editDiv = document.getElementById('DIVTHAT' + x)
  editDiv.contentEditable = 'false';
  editDiv.style = 'background:palegreen';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 105px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
}

h2 {
  background-color: none;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
}

button {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: solid green;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 1140px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
}

body {
  background-image: url("BG.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
}
```

```html
   
<center>
  <h1>FELRYN</h1>
</center>

<h2>Description of World:</h2>
<div id="DIVTHAT0" contentEditable="false" style="background:palegreen">Write the description here.</div>
<button id="WANNAEDIT?" class="pDiv" onclick="EDITTHIS(0); return false;"> Edit</button>
<button id="DONEEDIT?" onclick="ENDTHIS(0); return false;"> Done</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<button id="MULTIPLY!" onclick="AMPLIFYER()">Create New Feild.</button>

<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I noticed you used 'var count' in the 'function AMPLIFYER' as 'count++;'. What does 'count++' do? (I actually think this might have solved my problem, I just need to understand what you did.)

Comment: Also, I would like the Create New Field buttons to appear under the newly created field if that's possible. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: count++ is the same as saying count = count + 1 just increments one so that you have unique ids that will allow the edit and done buttons to know which div to go after

Comment: It now moves the multiply button

Comment: It seems to work well on Stack Overflow's, built in editor, but doesn't work on my computer. For Clarification, the Create New Field button doesn't work(Just on computer though). Again, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Is your javascript before or after your html?

Comment: After the head in the body. No matter now though! I got to work. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem was just asking sometimes JS will not find an element because it hasn't been created yet.thanks for the accept and vote :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the CREATION function from inside AMPLIFYER function and then the edit and done buttons work as you can see in the code snippet below. 
Let me know if this answers your question.

```html
<html>

<head>

 <title>Welcome to FELRYN</title>

 <style>

 h1{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 105px;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 300px;
 }

 h2{
  background-color: none;
  color: Black;
  font-size: 45px;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #6de1ff;
 }

 button {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border: solid green;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 div {
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 1140px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  font-size: 26px;
 }

 body{
  background-image: url("BG.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
 }

 </style>

</head>

<body>

 <script>

  function EDITTHIS(){
   document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').contentEditable='true'; 
   document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').style='background:yellow';
  }

  function ENDTHIS(){
   document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').contentEditable='false'; 
   document.getElementById('DESCRIPTION').style='background:palegreen';
  }
  
  function AMPLIFYER() {
        
   CREATION("DIV", "DIVTHAT", "Write Here.");
   CREATION("BUTTON", "EDITTHAT", "EDIT");
   CREATION("BUTTON", "DONETHAT", "DONE");
  }
  
  function CREATION(element, element_id, element_text){
  
   var element_a = document.createElement(element);
   element_a.setAttribute("id", element_id);
   var element_text = document.createTextNode(elemet_name);
   element_a.appendChild(element_text);
   document.body.appendChild(element_a);
  
  }

 </script>

 <center><h1>FELRYN</h1></center>

 <h2>Description of World:</h2>
 <div id="DESCRIPTION" contentEditable="false" style = "background:palegreen">Write the description here.</div>
 <br />

 <button id="WANNAEDIT?" onclick="EDITTHIS()"> Edit</button>
 <button id="DONEEDIT?" onclick="ENDTHIS()"> Done</button>

 <br />
 <br />
 <br />

 <button id="MULTIPLY!" onclick="AMPLIFYER()">Create New Feild.</button>

 <br />
 <br />
 <br />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes I understand I made that mistake, but even without the CREATION function in the AMPLIFYER function, the code works the same as in not functional. Thanks for your input though!